# XPATH How can i parse query xml Text with tags

Tags: java, xpath

I have xml file it Contents is

```
<sqlMap namespace="batchJobS">
  <select id="batchJobS.selectSiteId" parameterClass="java.util.HashMap" resultClass="String">

         SELECT TICDC.ATT1 AS V_BASE_CATE_TYPE
      FROM TM_INFO_COMM_DTL_CODE TICDC
     WHERE 1=1
       AND TICDC.USE_YN = 1
    <isEmpty property="p_yyyy_mm_dd">
           AND TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD') BETWEEN TICDC.APPLY_DATE AND TICDC.END_DATE
    </isEmpty>
    <isNotEmpty property="p_yyyy_mm_dd">
           AND #p_yyyy_mm_dd# BETWEEN TICDC.APPLY_DATE AND TICDC.END_DATE
    </isNotEmpty>
           AND TICDC.COMM_CODE = 'SYSINFO'
           AND TICDC.CODE = 'BASE_CATE_TYPE'
  </select>
  
  <insert id="batchJobS.doBatch01_005" parameterClass="java.util.HashMap">
      /* batchJobS.doBatch01_005 */
      INSERT INTO TM_DG_STATUS_REALTIME
      (WORK_MONTH, WORK_DG_KIND, WORK_DG_KIND_DESC, VALUE1)
      VALUES
      (#v_yyyy_mm_prev1d1m#, 'CM-SEC1', 'test', #qat_cnt_month_prev#)
  </insert>
</sqlMap>
```

then i parse this xml use xpath
and i get contentText but it didn't include any tags

this is my source :

```
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    factory.setValidating(false);
    factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
    factory.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/nonvalidating/load-external-dtd", false);
    DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(str));
    Document doc = builder.parse(file);

    XPathFactory xPathFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
    XPath xpath = xPathFactory.newXPath();
    XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("//select[@id='batchJobS.selectBaseCateType' and node()]");
    Object res = expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
    NodeList nodes = (NodeList) res;
    for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
        Element element = (Element) nodes.item(i);
        
        if (!element.getAttribute("id").isEmpty() || element.getAttribute("id") != null) {
            String id = element.getAttribute("id");
            String txt = element.getTextContent();
            map.put(id, txt);
            System.out.println(element.getTextContent());
        }
    }
```

How can i get all text ex)
/* batchJobS.selectBaseCateType */
SELECT TICDC.ATT1 AS V_BASE_CATE_TYPE
FROM TM_INFO_COMM_DTL_CODE TICDC
WHERE 1=1
AND TICDC.USE_YN = 1

AND TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD') BETWEEN TICDC.APPLY_DATE AND TICDC.END_DATE


AND #p_yyyy_mm_dd# BETWEEN TICDC.APPLY_DATE AND TICDC.END_DATE

AND TICDC.COMM_CODE = 'SYSINFO'
AND TICDC.CODE = 'BASE_CATE_TYPE'

please help me thank you

Comment: So you need to 1) get the `id` of an XML element and 2) map all the text it contains to that id? I believe the xpath you are trying to express is `//select[@id='batchJobS.selectBaseCateType']/ancestor-or-self::*`. However, this may not be sufficient for your objective.

Comment: i did what you say but i get only text
I want <isEmpty property="p_yyyy_mm_dd">
           AND TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD') BETWEEN TICDC.APPLY_DATE AND TICDC.END_DATE
    </isEmpty> 
these tag too